# Reduce call for service from Angular 2 components

Tags: angular, rest, api, service

Context: I have a service S call the data from the server and three components A, B, and C that call this service to get the same data. In Angular 2+, is there a way to tell component B, and C that the call for service is already called by A and just wait the data to handle?

I think I need to use cache or Observable for this case but I can't imagine how to do it?

**EDIT**

My service S:

```
currentAccount<Account>;

getCurrentAccount(): Observable<Account> {
    if (this.currentAccount && this.currentAccount.id) {
      return Observable.of(this.currentAccount);
    } else {
      return this.http.get<Account>(this.url).pipe(
        tap(account => {
          this.currentAccount = account;
    }));
}
```

Component A, B, and C now:

```
this.service.getCurrentAccount().subscribe(account => {
    // Do something
});
```

Imagine I have all 3 components above in the same container. How should I call with BehaviorSubject? These 3 components can also be used in other page which it will stay alone and need to call the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse. Since this is a Shared Service, you can expose a `BehaviorSubject` from this service `asObservable`. And then `subscribe` to it from all the three components.

Once the data is fetched in the service, you can call the `next` method on this `BehaviorSubject` and in all the three components, `subscribe` to this `BehaviorSubject`.

This is how it would translate into code:

Shared Service:

```
private sharedData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
sharedData$ = this.sharedData.asObservable();

getData() {
  this.http.get('YOUR_API_URL').subscribe(data => this.sharedData.next(data));
}
```

Component A:

```
this.sharedService.sharedData$.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
this.sharedService.getData();
```

Component B and Component C:

```
this.sharedService.sharedData$.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

**UPDATE:**

Considering that you don't want the call to go multiple times, you can simply expose the sharedData directly as an Object. Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript. So injecting the `SharedService` in all the three components and then referencing the `sharedData` will be the same for all the three Components. If the `sharedData` changes for one component(say A), then it will also get reflected for Components B and C as they are sharing the ref to the same object in memory.

Your implementation of the SharedService will then change to the following:

```
sharedData;

getData() {
  return this.http.get('YOUR_API_URL').pipe(
    tap(data => this.sharedData = data)
  );
}
```

Now just call this `getData` method in any component after checking whether `sharedData` is `undefined` or not.

So in all components A, B, and C,

```
if(this.sharedService.sharedData) {
  // Use sharedData
  this.data = this.sharedService.sharedData;
}
else {
  this.sharedService.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

Comment: thank you, I will try to apply it and return to you :)

Comment: Don't expose the subject expose the observable instead like this.sharedData.asObservable() https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

Comment: Good point. I was really looking for a reason regarding this. Now I know the reason. Thanks. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am applying it, another question, how can I add an update to the shareData directly?

Comment: I will add some modification into my question to clarify something

Comment: If component B, and C are used in other page, how can I let it call the data itself, in your example, I saw only A called the data, B and C just subscribe to the change in the shareData, not call it

Comment: Since `B` and `C` also inject `SharedService` as a dependency, they can call `sharedService.getData();` as well.

Comment: I got it but how it will save the call for the data, beacause each component A, B, and C will call the service one time, so in total we will have 3 requests for the same data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180255/discussion-between-siddajmera-and-tho-vo).